# Запрос с циклом из БД

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте есть всего две таблицы `post` и `comments`, мне нужно вытащить пост и все комментарии по `id` поста:
`post`

```
| id | title | text|
```

и `comments`

```
|id_post | author | comment_text |
```

Деревенский метод конечно работает,

```
$a = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM post WEHER id='.$_GET["id"].'');

 while ($b = mysql_fetch_array($a)) 
{
$c= mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from comments where id_post = '$b['id']'"));
}
```

но хочется без циклов пробовал так, но не работает:

```
SELECT 
   t1.title, 
   t1.text,
   t2.author, 
   t2.comment_text 
FROM post t1, comments t2 
JOIN post ON t2.id_post = post.id 
WHERE post.id = $_GET['id']
```

Answer (score 2):

Уверен, что поле id  уникально во всей таблице post. Поэтому, зная id, можно сразу выбрать комментарии.

```
select author,comment_text from comments where id_post=$id;
```

[Упражняйтесь](http://sql-ex.ru)

Comment: В таком случае только первый комментарий выводится а остальных как, их же много?

Answer (score 2):

```
$sql = "
SELECT 
   t1.title, 
   t1.text,
   t2.author, 
   t2.comment_text 
FROM post t1
LEFT JOIN comments t2 ON t2.id_post = t1.id 
WHERE t1.id = ".intval($_GET['id']).";";
```

Кстати, в таблицу Комментарии я бы тоже уникальный ID(-комментария) добавил. Например, чтоб было удобно удалять)

Comment: Мне нравится ваш метод, осталось прикрепить как то:) щас..

Comment: Хм... тоже только первый комментарий выводится

Comment: Плохо. В выводе текст поста будет повторятся столько раз, сколько к нему комментариев, и я думаю тип поля `TEXT` и размер может быть какой угодно.

Comment: @bemulima. 
1. Тогда вопрос у вас же в поле post_id комментария, находится Id поста, к которому комментарий? 
То есть у вас в таблице comments есть записи, у которых post_id одинаковый.

2. Результат этого запроса у вас обрабатывается циклом вида:

    while ($row = @mysql_fetch_array($req))
    {
          if ($lastPost != $row['id'])
          {
               Вывод поста
          }    
          $lastPost != $row['id']

          Вывод комментария
    }

Не забудьте добавить  t1.id,

Comment: @KaZaца - молодец - возьми с полки пирожок)))

...Сорри. Не удержался.

В данном вопросе соль, как по мне, не показать как правильно с точки зрения оптимизации, а как вообще стоятся join'ы.

Да. Конкретно в данном случае лушче сделать двумя запросами - посты отдельно, камменты отдельно. 

Но в целом и общем очень часто бывают задачи, когда избыток данных минимален, а выигрыш по быстродействию (за счет уменьшения количества запросов с дохрена до одного) - существенен.

Answer (score 2):

Цикл тут нужен, но у вас он не там. Вы получите только 1 коментарий из всех

```
$c=array();
$a=mysql_query("select * from comments where id_post='$_GET[id]'");
while($b=mysql_fetch_assoc($a)) $c[]=$b;
```

Comment: Я думаю тут можно обойти без циклов

Comment: Вы правы, я только туда не написал это, чтоб текст был по меньше объема

Comment: просто судя по названию `mysql_fetch_array()` иногда людям кажется, что данная фукция возвращает все строки из результата - это не верно (http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) кроме того пора уже давно переходить на mysqli